# Limit of an integral - $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\int_{a}^{b}e^{\frac{-x^2}{1 + t^2}} dx}{\sqrt\pi \sqrt{1+t^2}} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'd like to show that

> $$
> \lim_{t \to \infty}  \frac{\int_{a}^{b}e^{\frac{-x^2}{1 + t^2}} dx}{\sqrt\pi \sqrt{1+t^2}} = 0
> $$

with $a, b $ constant. It seems pretty intuitive to me that this is true, but I don't know what to do to *show* it. I don't need to be massively rigorous, so there's no need for $\epsilon, \delta$-proofs, I just need to give a valid argument. Can I take the limits of the numerator and denominator independently?

Comment: Yes you can.  The numerator goes to $b-a$, the denominator goes to infinity.

Comment: why is it that I am allowed to do this? Is it obviously allowed? @Ron Gordon.

Comment: It's allowed because that's a property of limits. Provided the bottom limit is not 0, you can definitely do this.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you need? It is too easy. The integrand is between $0$ and $1$, so the integral is $\lt b-a$. Then the big $\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{t^2+1}$ kills it.

Comment: yes, that was the right question. I just had a brain fail. @AndreNicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe that
$$
0\le\left|\int_a^b \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{1+t^2}\right)dx\right|\le \left|\int_a^b 1 dx\right| = |b-a|.
$$
Thus
$$
0\le \left|\frac{\int_a^b \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{1+t^2}\right)dx}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right| \le \frac{|b-a|}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{1+t^2}}
$$
and we are done by the squeeze theorem.